# How to echo special characters in batch file?

Tags: sql, oracle, batch-file, escaping

I want to pass below query to `sqlplus` command.

> ```
> select 'Version ID:   ' || a1.BACKUP_VERSION  || CHR(13) || CHR(10)||'Status:  ' || a1.STORAGE_STATUS ||  CHR(13) || CHR(10)|| 'Distribution ID:  ' || a1.DISTRIBUTION_ID FROM epc1_distrib_version a1;
> ```

When I echo this on screen using caret `^` sign it works well.

```
echo select 'Version ID:   ' ^|^| a1.BACKUP_VERSION  ^|^| CHR(13) ^|^| CHR(10)^|^|'Status:  ' ^|^| a1.STORAGE_STATUS ^|^|  CHR(13) ^|^| CHR(10)^|^| 'Distribution ID:  ' ^|^| a1.DISTRIBUTION_ID FROM epc1_distrib_version a1;
```

It displays the correct query string. But when I use this in my batch file it doesn't work. This is the code I am trying to run:

```
@ECHO OFF
echo Connecting to Database...
echo +++++++++++++++++++++++++
(
echo user/pass@instance
echo select 'Version ID:   ' ^|^| a1.BACKUP_VERSION  ^|^| CHR(13) ^|^| CHR(10)^|^|'Status:  ' ^|^| a1.STORAGE_STATUS ^|^|  CHR(13) ^|^| CHR(10)^|^| 'Distribution ID:  ' ^|^| a1.DISTRIBUTION_ID FROM epc1_distrib_version a1;
)| sqlplus -s
echo +++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

It only shows this:

> ```
> Connecting to Database...
> +++++++++++++++++++++++++
> user/pass@instance
> select 'Version ID:   ' || a1.BACKUP_VERSION  || CHR(13
> +++++++++++++++++++++++++
> ```

It doesn't pass query to `sqlplus` command, how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the closing parentheses like `^)`. Your `echo` command is placed inside of a block of code between a pair of parentheses `()`; any unescaped closing parenthesis is interpreted as end of that block. So the fixed code looks like:

```
echo select 'Version ID:   ' ^|^| a1.BACKUP_VERSION  ^|^| CHR^(13^) ^|^| CHR^(10^)^|^|'Status:  ' ^|^| a1.STORAGE_STATUS ^|^|  CHR^(13^) ^|^| CHR^(10^)^|^| 'Distribution ID:  ' ^|^| a1.DISTRIBUTION_ID FROM epc1_distrib_version a1;
```

I escaped the opening parentheses `^(` as well, although this is not absolutely necessary, for the sake of legibility of the code; so it is clear which parenthesis are functional and which are cosmetic.

In the batch script you are using a pipe `|` to pass the output over to the `sqlplus` command; this requires double-escaping like this:

```
@echo off
echo Connecting to Database...
echo +++++++++++++++++++++++++
(
echo user/pass@instance
echo select 'Version ID:   ' ^^^|^^^| a1.BACKUP_VERSION  ^^^|^^^| CHR^^^(13^^^) ^^^|^^^| CHR^^^(10^^^)^^^|^^^|'Status:  ' ^^^|^^^| a1.STORAGE_STATUS ^^^|^^^|  CHR^^^(13^^^) ^^^|^^^| CHR^^^(10^^^)^^^|^^^| 'Distribution ID:  ' ^^^|^^^| a1.DISTRIBUTION_ID FROM epc1_distrib_version a1;
) | sqlplus -s
echo +++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

This is because a pipe creates new command prompt instances for each side of `|`, where the code portion is executed; so special characters need to be hidden from the main command prompt instance where the batch file is run from, and form the instance created by the pipe process.

---

Another option is to place the string to output in betweeen a pair of double-quotes `""` (assuming that the string itself does not contain such characters). However, a command line like `echo "..."` cannot be used because the `""`  were included in the output, which we do not want.

A trick is to use `set /P` which is intended to prompt a user for a value of an environment variable. We do not need the variable (`#`) herein but the prompt text:

```
set /P "#=select 'Version ID:   ' || a1.BACKUP_VERSION  || CHR(13) || CHR(10)||'Status:  ' || a1.STORAGE_STATUS ||  CHR(13) || CHR(10)|| 'Distribution ID:  ' || a1.DISTRIBUTION_ID FROM epc1_distrib_version a1;"
```

To avoid this command waiting for user input, we pipe an `echo` into it (just a single `_` character):

```
echo _| set /P "#=select 'Version ID:   ' || a1.BACKUP_VERSION  || CHR(13) || CHR(10)||'Status:  ' || a1.STORAGE_STATUS ||  CHR(13) || CHR(10)|| 'Distribution ID:  ' || a1.DISTRIBUTION_ID FROM epc1_distrib_version a1;"
```

Finally, let us use all this in the batch script:

```
@echo off
echo Connecting to Database...
echo +++++++++++++++++++++++++
(
echo user/pass@instance
echo _| set /P "#=select 'Version ID:   ' || a1.BACKUP_VERSION  || CHR(13) || CHR(10)||'Status:  ' || a1.STORAGE_STATUS ||  CHR(13) || CHR(10)|| 'Distribution ID:  ' || a1.DISTRIBUTION_ID FROM epc1_distrib_version a1;"
echo/
) | sqlplus -s
echo +++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Opposed to `echo`, the text displayed by `set /P` is not terminated by a final line-break; that is why I inserted the line `echo/`, which outputs a single line-break.

Comment: It works, but only without the pipe `|`, which I forgot about, sorry; see my edit...

Comment: I just added an alternative method using `set /P` and `""`; such avoids need of (double-)escaping...

Answer (score 2):

You could use carets, but when you want to pipe it, then you need to escape every special character two times and with quotes the whole thing is nasty.

You could use delayed expansion to avoid this

```
set "sql=select 'Version ID:   ' || a1.BACKUP_VERSION  || CHR(13) || CHR(10)||'Status:  ' || a1.STORAGE_STATUS ||  CHR(13) || CHR(10)|| 'Distribution ID:  ' || a1.DISTRIBUTION_ID FROM epc1_distrib_version a1;"

(
  echo user/pass@instance
  cmd /v:on /c "echo ^!sql^!"
) | sqlplus -s
```

Btw. to test your escaping you can replace `sqlplus` with `more` to see what you really echo